# Office 2007 New Message Window Does Not Respond

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2007, configuration-management

I am using Windows XP and every time I open the new message window in Office 2007 the window can't be dragged, can't be closed by clicking on the window. I can close or move or maximize the window by right clicking on the taskbar.

Some other information; The office is deployed using Alteris and it does take a long time to open on a Dual Core 3GB Ram machine.

Has anyone ran into this issue?

Answer (score 1):

can you repair the install through add/remove programs in the control panel?

Comment: No it is deployed through Alteris, so there is no install/uninstall menu.

Comment: The fact that your using Altiris has nothing to do with the fact that there is no t listed in Add/Remove Programs.  Altiris is just the delivery method and it is the way in-which software package is being created that is causing this not to show up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried detect and repair yet?  Found on the help menu, I believe it needs access to the installation files, either on the cd or a shared folder, fixes some dialog box problems we have with outlook.  Good lUck!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting/renaming the MS Office keys for a given users registry hive in their profile.  This will trigger MS Office to rebuild the registry keys which are require by the Office application loading the default settings from the software installation instructions.